# OpAmp eventually burns/malfunctions

Tags: operational-amplifier

I try to drive a galvo-mirror with a dual OpAmp [AD8532](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD8531_8532_8534.pdf). No spec sheet for the mirror, but it is about 16 Ohm and takes about 50mA at 2Vp-p, if I measured correctly. The OpAmp starts malfunctioning after a while. I could not determine when/what causes it to malfunction, but it stops to provide all the required power. It seems like it gets fried up a little. The only thing I could think of right now, are the reversed currents caused by induction. I will try to add reversed diode to each of the outputs, but I am not sure if the problem will go away. Do not want to burn more OpAmps. Any suggestions what else should be added to the circuit below, to make it right?

[image]

Comment: What's the frequency?  Does if fail even at low frequency?  What about if you replace the galvo- with a resistor? (16 ohms)  If you know the inductance you can add an RC in parallel to the inductor to make it look resistive to the opamps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try adding Schottky diodes (eg. 1N5819) from the output of each op amp to ground and +5 (four diodes total).

Also put a resistor (something like 1K) in series with the inverting inputs (two resistors total).

You should also make sure there is good bypassing on the 5V supply. Perhaps 10uF ceramic in parallel with 1000uF/6.3V low impedance electrolytic.

The total power dissipation with the output railed could be as much as ~400mW in each amplifier so if you're using anything other than the SOIC package with a nice copper pour around it (and maybe a stick-on heatsink), you could just be overheating the chip. The SC-70 package would die quickly if railed. Maybe put a resistor from the input (if it can be disconnected) to your 2.5V reference so that if the input is disconnected the current drops to about zero.

Ah, I missed that you're using the *dual* op-amp, as Andy notes, so the power dissipation is doubled. If you switch to two singles in SOIC you might be okay.

Comment: It is a SOIC package, but it did not seem to be heating up. Also, it does not rail out ( +1.5V to 3.5V swings on one input and 2.5VDC on the other). So, you do not think the reverse currents would be the cause of it? Did you mean make 1k resistor as a feedback resistor?

Comment: Yes, just from the output to the inverting input, so that too much current cannot flow into the input if the output exceeds the rails. See the section on overvoltage protection- they recommend input current is limited to 5mA maximum, so the Schottky diodes and resistor will pretty much do that. Also, see my edit on bypass capacitors.

Comment: @Naz it's not heating up?  Have you tried touching it with your finger tip?

Comment: @GeorgeHerold Believe it or not, but after 2 min it is not even warm. Of course, it is in the socket, not on the PCB. But if it was heating up, it would still feel warm.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Why do you suggest two diodes (one to +5V and the other to GND) instead of just one from output to GND?

Comment: I suggest two diodes because the output could be driven beyond the rails in either direction, not just negative. Maybe something to do with what current is flowing when power is interrupted.

Answer (score 3):

When supplying a peak of 1.4142 volts above midrail there will be a current flow of 62.5mA RMS (1volt/16 ohms) - this current is sourced from a transistor that is connected to 5V hence it, (the transistor), will dissipate a power of possibly over 100 mW. This is repeated on the other bridged op-amp but power dissipation on that side will be slightly higher because it is a mid-rail generator - maybe a total power dissipation in the device of 300 mW.

This device is going to struggle to live for very long because you are asking too much of it. I did mention that op-amps weren't suitable in your deleted question!!

The device is rated to operate at 85degC absolute maximum and with a package that possibly is rated thermally at 100C/watt you are going to get a 30 degC rise above ambient. Without proper heatsinking it's going to fry because the local temeperature around the device will just rise up due to the local power dissipated. Maybe if you used a small fan?

Comment: I guess if Spehro's advice does not work, I will have to go with something more power full, as you suggested. The fact that the original board uses exactly this dual opamp kept me convinced that I could make it work too.

Comment: You could try lowering the supply voltage.  Say 4 volts.. and adjust all your DC offsets accordingly.

Comment: @Naz - you should consider all the help you've been given is worth upvoting and/or accepting some answers. From my perspective, I've spent more than a few tens of minutes giving you good advice on this question (and the deleted one) and I'm not aware that you have been gracious enough to recognize good advice yet.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold I do not want the signal be close to rails, because I am afraid it will not perform as good.

Comment: @Naz, Grin well it's not performing now, so what's to lose?  If I'm reading you correctly it's only a 2Vp-p signal, so you'd still have 1 volt of head room.  But you say it's not heating up.  That's strange.  What's the inductance and the frequency?

Comment: It has to be heating up else the impedance aint 16 ohms and/or the voltage across the load aint 1V RMS.

Comment: Even at just 2 Vpp, 0.707 V(rms), the current is 44.2 mA(rms), and each of the two opamps is dissipating over 110 mW.

Comment: Strange... It's been running for more than 10min. I measure 2Vp-p+2.5VDC and 2.5VDC on the outputs respectively, while the mirror is connected and running. I could barely feel that it is warm.

Comment: I must add that the sawtooth looks as it should, but the offset on the other output is not a horizontal line - looks sinusoidish with small 200mVp-p amplitude.

Comment: @Naz, If this is the case then you might have to consider that the impedance of the coil is much smaller than you think and op-amps are even more inappropriate (or that 2nd device is about to fail?).

Comment: Interesting. The voltage waveform on the "reference" output is the result of the galvo current flowing through the nonzero output impedance of that driver. This suggests that the current waveform is also "sinusoidish" -- rather than "sawtoothish" -- which implies that the inductive reactance of the galvo may be more significant than its DC resistance. A sawtooth voltage applied to a pure inductance will give you a series of parabolas, which will appear "sinusoidish" (with the peaks one side being "pointier" than the other) under certain circumstances.

Comment: Note that the galvo deflection is proportional to the current through it, not the voltage. So, if your goal is to have a sawtooth deflection pattern, and if the galvo is primarily an inductive load, you're actually going to have to apply a voltage waveform that looks like a series of low duty cycle pulses. You might want to study the sweep circuits that were used on old CRT-based TVs and monitors.

Comment: @DaveTweed I really need a ramp of steps. What I do is deflect the mirror to one end and then provide voltage steps until the mirror is deflected to the other end. Then, I swing the mirror back to the initial position (wait a few us to make sure it is stabilized) and repeat the cycle. Thus I do not really care what happens at the edges of the sawtooth, only when the mirror deflects in steps from one maximum to the other.

Comment: A few microcseconds? Really? How fast is this galvo, anyway? Do you have a datasheet? And what's the frequency of your test waveform? I'm getting a feeling that you're going to want a much more sophisticated driver circuit than what you've got now. Start by driving the two opamps as a true H-bridge, instead of the half-bridge you're currently using. And consider actively monitoring the galvo current, using that as a feedback signal to correct for its complex load impedance.

Comment: @DaveTweed I apologize for giving a lot of false info. I do not have the spec sheet for the mirror, so I use trial-error method to make this work. The period of the "saw tooth" is 400ms. Fist 200ms it stays fully deflected, and the other 200ms it makes 1024 steps to the other extreme. Then it is quickly deflected back and new cycle begins. If you believe that a true H-bridge is needed, could you, please, provide a suggested circuit?